# Different definitions for the complex inner product.

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, definition, quantum-mechanics

I have asked this question on P.S.E. and have gotten some nice answers, but I felt I might get even more satisfactory answers if I post it here.

"I have just now noticed that Griffiths (in his book *Introduction to Quantum Mechanics*) defines the complex inner product as $\big<z,w\big>=\sum_{i=1}^n\overline{z}_iw_i$. In all mathematics books (I study math and physics) I have ever come across, it is defined as $\big<z,w\big>=\sum_{i=1}^nz_i\overline{w}_i$. Maybe there is an answer to this question, maybe there isn't, but why on earth is this defined differently in physics than in math?"

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/215783/why-does-griffiths-define-the-complex-inner-product-differently

I'll be glad to see someone make the case for mathematics, and let me know if the question shouldn't be asked here.

Comment: Because we physicists like to keep our vectors in the same order when we convert to matrix expressions: $$\langle v, w \rangle = [v]^\dagger [w] = \pmatrix{v_1^* & \cdots & v_n^*}\pmatrix{w_1 \\ \vdots \\ w_n}$$ and mathematicians don't (presumably just to make it harder on themselves :p).

Answer (score 2):

It was von Neumann who was the first to axiomatically define the inner product as a pairing in the manner it is done today. So he set the standard. Interestingly, von Neumann was the one who coined the term Hilbert Space, and effectively tied Hilbert's name to this abstract development, instead of his own (von Neumann was Hilbert's assistant during that time.) Von Neumann then developed the abstract theory of normal and Hermitian operators in a series of 3 papers from 1929-1932 which remain, in substance, the basis of modern accounts. Dirac introduced bra-ket in 1939.

Comment: So was it Von Neumann who came up with the idea that for every observable quantity there is a corresponding self-adjoint linear operator, and the eigenvalues of this operator are the possible values for that observable quantity? And to get the probability of observing any particular eigenvalue, you take the state of your physical system and write it as a linear combination of the eigenvectors for the relevant self-adjoint operator; the squares of the magnitudes of the coefficients in that expansion are interpreted as probabilities. Was that all Von Neumann's idea? What a genius.

Comment: @littleO : There was a lot going on those years, and a lot of credit to go around. Dirac and Schrodinger were brilliant; they did the Physics.

Comment: @littleO : There are a couple of brilliant early examples that come to mind in Quantum that are way beyond any Math-only development, such as where Schrodinger first introduced operator formalism to solve the Quantum Harmonic Oscillator problem, and diagonalize the Fourier transform. And, where Dirac's operator methods were used to explain strange particle tracks through the existence of anti-matter.

Answer (score 1):

It is just a convention.

@Bye_World's explanation is a good justification of the physicists point of view.

We mathematicians probably just thought "We want it to be complex linear in one slot, and complex antilinear in the other slot.  Might as well make the first one complex linear."